# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne exception when inserting entry to Javers Mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, maven, javers

I am able to insert the data to mongodb collection. Same time Javers framework trying to insert the data to jv_snapshots collection. Data insertion to jv_snapshots collection is failing and getting below exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult;
at org.javers.repository.mongo.MongoRepository.lambda$persistSnapshots$3(MongoRepository.java:231) ~[javers-persistence-mongo-5.11.1.jar:na]
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.javers.repository.mongo.MongoRepository.persistSnapshots(MongoRepository.java:230) ~[javers-persistence-mongo-5.11.1.jar:na]
at org.javers.repository.mongo.MongoRepository.persist(MongoRepository.java:88) ~[javers-persistence-mongo-5.11.1.jar:na]
at org.javers.repository.api.JaversExtendedRepository.persist(JaversExtendedRepository.java:154) ~[javers-core-5.11.1.jar:na]
at org.javers.core.JaversCore.persist(JaversCore.java:108) ~[javers-core-5.11.1.jar:na]
at org.javers.core.JaversCore.commit(JaversCore.java:89) ~[javers-core-5.11.1.jar:na]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversCommitAdvice.commitObject(JaversCommitAdvice.java:81) ~[javers-spring-5.11.1.jar:na]
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.springdata.AbstractSpringAuditableRepositoryAspect.lambda$onSave$0(AbstractSpringAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:28) ~[javers-spring-5.11.1.jar:na]
at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.springdata.AbstractSpringAuditableRepositoryAspect.onSave(AbstractSpringAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:27) ~[javers-spring-5.11.1.jar:na]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.springdata.JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.onSaveExecuted(JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:44) ~[javers-spring-5.11.1.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:626) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.afterReturning(AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.java:66) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.baeldung.javers.service.StoreService.updateProductPrice(StoreService.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
at com.baeldung.javers.service.StoreService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d68ccd83.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.baeldung.javers.service.StoreService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8a1b744b.updateProductPrice(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.baeldung.javers.web.StoreController.updateProductPrice(StoreController.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
```

**My pom.xml file is:**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <springBootVersion>2.1.6.RELEASE</springBootVersion>
    <spockVersion>1.2-groovy-2.5</spockVersion>
    <groovyVersion>2.5.5</groovyVersion>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
        <artifactId>javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Repository class have @JaversSpringDataAuditable annotation.

Entity Class have following imports:

import org.javers.core.metamodel.annotation.Entity;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

The project is working fine if I use any SQL based DB instead of mongoDB with the corresponding changes(changes in pom.xml and application.properties).

**jv_snapshots collection is getting created during the project startup but the insertion is failing. Also, jv_head_id collection not getting created. I doubt, the issue is due to some mongodb  dependency/library version issue or conflict issue. Can you please try to help me to solve this.**

My project is based on **Javers + Java 8 + Spring boot + Spring Data + Maven + MongoDB** combination.

Comment: This issue got resolved when I added one more dependency: 

    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
  <artifactId>javers-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.11.1</version>
 </dependency>

But, this is not mentioned in the Javerse official documentation. This need to add additionally if the project is based on **Javers+Java 8+Spring boot+Spring Data+Maven+MongoDB**

The above dependency is not required to add additionally if the project is based on Javers+Java 8+Spring boot+Spring Data+**Gradle**+MongoDB  or  Javers+Java 8+Spring boot+Spring Data+Maven+**SQL**

Comment: Is it possible to provide custom names to jv_snapshots and jv_head_id in spring boot mongodb project ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I'm not using javers ..What should I do?..Showing this --java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertMany(Ljava/util/List;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/InsertManyResult;

Answer (score 6):

Probably you have two different version of `mongodb-driver` on your classpath. Make sure that you are using the same version of `mongodb-driver` as Javers does. See https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.javers/javers-persistence-mongo/5.11.2/jar

Comment: This issue got resolved when I added one more dependency: 

    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
  <artifactId>javers-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.11.1</version>
 </dependency>

But, this is not mentioned in the Javerse official documentation. This need to add additionally if the project is based on **Javers+Java 8+Spring boot+Spring Data+Maven+MongoDB**

The above dependency is not required to add additionally if the project is based on Javers+Java 8+Spring boot+Spring Data+**Gradle**+MongoDB  or  Javers+Java 8+Spring boot+Spring Data+Maven+**SQL**

Comment: Is it possible to provide custom names to jv_snapshots and jv_head_id in spring boot mongodb project ?

Answer (score 3):

My issue is unlikely to be the same as yours but it does result in **the exact same error**. I was attempting to save a document using  `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations` and forgot to assign the `id` field:

```
myDocument.setId(ObjectId.get()); //I was missing this line
operations.save(myDocument);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening when upgrading from the MongoDB legacy API to the newer API.

Using the same version of all MongoDB dependency is mandatory to prevent this kind of error. But, when a dependency was compiled against an earlier version of the `mongodb-java-driver` and not against `mongodb-driver-core` this is not sufficient. The return type of `insertOne` was changed and it seems that the return type is part of the class format, which then cannot find a matching method in the newer `mongodb-driver-core` API. Hence the dependency using the legacy version must be updated and compiled against the new API.

`insertOne` is returning `void` in `mongodb-java-driver` [legacy version 3.12](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#insertOne(TDocument)) but in `mongodb-driver-core` [version 4.5](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.5/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#insertOne(TDocument)) is is returning `InsertOneResult`.